# Which version of Ubuntu is best suited for a Pentium 4

Tags: versions, cpu

The question is pretty self-explanatory. I have a 2.8Ghz, 1GB RAM PC at my office. Windows is really slow on it and the Android Emulator never works properly on it. I am sure that Linux will definitely improve performance. What I can't decide is which version I should install?

P.S. Where can I find older versions of Ubuntu?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I see "ph1b" is best answer. You can download ubuntu 11.10, then update and finally download xfce or lxde desktop. lxde is lighter than xfce.

You can also download lubuntu like "Vic" said, but I tried and faced problem with it. I don't know why but you can try and you won't lose anything.

Anyway I think if you download ubuntu 11.10 with the default unity 3D, you will not face any problem anyway because it's [requirements](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/SystemRequirements#Ubuntu_Desktop_Edition) are 1GB RAM and 1 GHz processor only.

So download ubuntu 11.10 and try.

Comment: Why ubuntu when lubuntu is available?
For the best support of lxde you must install lubuntu

installing lxde crashes gnome-shell menu atleast for me :)

Comment: @AboobackerMk: That sounds coincidental. I can't see any reason why installing lxde would crash any running system.

Comment: I mean after installing lxde it it added every entries in the PATH folders are added to menu  it makes problem in gnome-shell menu 


why he have to download entire ubuntu when unity is not needed?
Lubuntu  is optimised for lxde so it is better:)

Comment: as i said man for him to try download ubuntu Specials that system requiements for ubuntu meet his computer and too as i said i download lubuntu before twice install it in my real computer and once in virtualbox and two way i face problem i don't why so the best thing to try all and he will know the best distro for him of course

Answer (score 3):

Try Lubuntu, which is now one the 'official' supported versions of Ubuntu. It uses a lightweight window manager and it fairly races along.

There are no problems using synaptic to install whatever you like, though it comes with some preinstalled lightweight alternatives to some standard Ubuntu progs and it uses standard repositories.

Recommended.

Vic

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend Using the latest Ubuntu and then not Using the standard-interface, but use another one.

```
sudo apt-get install lxde
```

Then log off, click in the loginscren on config and choose LXDE. Works pretty well on old machines.

Answer (score 0):

Definitely Lubuntu. It has always boasted low hardware requirements for an Ubuntu distro. Don't expect any fancy toys, but it's honest and simple.

[Click here for their site](http://www.lubuntu.net)